# Collect the data (two parameters) between two keywords (variable+string) from ini file

Tags: bash, shell, text, cut, collect

I have a txt.ini file with content (I cannot modify the structure of this file):

[txt.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrVqJ.jpg)

txt.ini

```
[person_0:public]
name=john
groups=0,1,2
age=30

[person_0:private]
married=false
weight=190
height=100

[person_1:public]
name=mark
groups=0,4
age=28

[person_1:private]
married=false
weight=173
height=70

[person_2:public]
name=tony
groups=3,4
age=30

[person_3:private]
married=true
weight=202
height=120
```

I have a variable "person" which takes the value one of: person_0, person_1, person_3 in the loop and I would like to collect the person's data like age and groups for every 'person' one by one.

My idea is to cut out the part between $person:public and $person:private and after that collect

e.g.
set variable person=person_1
output:
groups=0,4
age=28

I prepared the code in bash (persons is a list of person_0, person_1, person2):

```
for person in ${persons[@]}; do
    file="txt.ini"
    echo "$person"
    a=$(awk -v a=$person":private" -v b=$person":public" '/a/{found=0} {if(found) print} /b/{found=1}' $file)

    IFS=$'\n' lines=($a)
    IFS='=' read grouplist grouplist_values <<< ${lines[1]}
    IFS='=' read age age_values <<< ${lines[4]}
    echo "Group list = $grouplist_values"
    echo "Age = $age_values"
```

Group list and age are empty. Output:

```
person_0
Group list =
Age =

person_1
Group list =
Age =

person_2
Group list =
Age =
```

Expected:

```
person_0
Group list =0,1,2
Age =30

person_1
Group list =0,4
Age =28

person_2
Group list =3,4
Age =30
```

I will use this data "per person" in another part of my code. I'm working on files with different number of "persons".

I really don't know what is wrong.

I tried also:

```
#export person="person_0"
#a=$(awk '/ENVIRON["person"]:private/{found=0} {if(found) print} /ENVIRON["person"]:public/{found=1}' $file)
```

and

```
private=$person":private"
public=$person":public"
echo "private=$private"
echo "public=$public"
a=$(awk -v a=$private" -v b=$public '/a/{found=0} {if(found) print} /b/{found=1}' $config_file)
```

but output was the same:

```
person_0
private=person_0:private
public=person_0:public
Group list =
Age =
```

What is strange for me - when I hardcode range of cutting it works properly:

```
a=$(awk '/person_0:private/{found=0} {if(found) print} /person_0:public/{found=1}' $file)
```

or

```
a=$(awk '/person_1:private/{found=0} {if(found) print} /person_1:public/{found=1}' $file)
```

Do you have any idea how can I collect this data in a clever way?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: for person=person_0 => groups=0,1,2
age=30 and for person=person_1 => groups=0,4 age 28 and for person=person_2 => groups=3,4 age=30

Comment: fixed passed code to "for person in ${persons[@]}; do" persons is a list of person_0, person_1, person_2

Comment: right, I changed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -v RS='' '                          # split the records on the blank lines
/public/ {                              # "public" record
    split($1, a, /[\[:]/); print a[2]   # extract the "person_xx" substring
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {         # iterate over the lines of the record
        split($i, a, /=/)
        if (a[1] == "groups") print "Group list =" a[2]
        else if (a[1] == "age") print "Age =" a[2]
    }
    print ""                            # insert a blank line
}
' txt.ini
```

Output:

```
person_0
Group list =0,1,2
Age =30

person_1
Group list =0,4
Age =28

person_2
Group list =3,4
Age =30
```

- By setting `awk` variable `RS` to the null string, the records are
  separated by blank lines and the fields are separated by the newline
  character.
- Assuming the desired data are included in the `public` block,
  we can parse the fields of the `public` record one by one.

**[Edit]**
According to the OP's comment, here is the updated version:

```
#!/bin/bash

persons=("person_0")                            # list of desired person(s)
for person in "${persons[@]}"; do               # loop over the bash array
    awk -v RS='' -v person="$person" '          # assign awk variables
    $1 ~ person ":public" {                     # "public" record of the person
        split($1, a, /[\[:]/); print a[2]       # extract the "person_xx" substring
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {             # iterate over the lines of the record
            split($i, a, /=/)
            if (a[1] == "groups") print "Group list =" a[2]
            else if (a[1] == "age") print "Age =" a[2]
        }
    }
    ' txt.ini
    echo                                        # insert a blank line
done
```

- You can assign the `persons` array to whoever you want.
- The pattern `$1 ~ person ":public"` tests if the 1st field of the record `$1` (e.g. `[person_0:public]`) matches the awk variable `person` (passed with the `-v` option) followed by a string ":public".

Obviously the awk script repeats reading the `txt.ini` file multiple
times as many as the #elements in the `persons` array.
If the `text.ini` file is long and/or the `persons` array has many elements,
the loop will be inefficient. Here is another variant:

```
#!/bin/bash

persons=("person_0" "person_1")         # bash array just for an example
awk -v RS='' -v persons_list="${persons[*]}" '
                                        # persons_list is a blank separated list of persons
BEGIN {
    split(persons_list, a)              # split persons_list back to an array
    for (i in a) persons[a[i]]          # create a new array indexed by person
}
/public/ {                              # "public" record
    split($1, a, /[\[:]/)               # extract the "person_xx" substring
    if (a[2] in persons) {              # if the person exists in the list
        print a[2]
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {     # iterate over the lines of the record
            split($i, a, /=/)
            if (a[1] == "groups") print "Group list =" a[2]
            else if (a[1] == "age") print "Age =" a[2]
        }
        print ""                        # insert a blank line
    }
}
' txt.ini
```

Please note it assumes the person string does not contain whitespace characters.
If so, change the delimiter when assigning the `persons_list` to an unused
character such as a comma.

Comment: How can I collect the data from only one person? Eg. person_0 and not print all. I mean in the top of the code I have a variable which choose one person eg. at this time x="person_0" and how can I set group and age variables?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer. Hope it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- for a given person (eg, `person_0`) display said person along with the associated (`public`) fields for `groups` and `age`
- no indication has been given for what we're suppose to do with this data so assume, for now, we just need to print to stdout
- list of persons to process is in `bash` array `persons[]`
- the strings `:public` and `:private` only show up in the block headers

One `awk` idea where we use the `split()` function to parse a line based on different delimiters:

```
awk '
FNR==NR    { persons[$1]
             next
           }
/:private/ { printme=0 }
/:public/  { printme=0

             split($1,arr,"[]:[]")
             person=arr[2]

             if (person in persons) {
                printme=1
                printf "%s%s\n", pfx, person
                pfx="\n"
             }
           }
printme    { split($1,arr,"=")
             if (arr[1] == "groups") print "Group list =" arr[2]
             if (arr[1] == "age")    print "Age ="        arr[2]
           }
' <(printf "%s\n" "${persons[@]}") txt.ini
```

A variation on this theme using a multi-character input field delimiter:

```
awk -F"[]:=[]" '
FNR==NR       { persons[$1]
                next
              }
$3=="private" { printme=0 }
$3=="public"  { printme=0
                if ($2 in persons) {
                   printme=1
                   printf "%s%s\n", pfx, $2
                   pfx="\n"
                }
              }
printme && $1=="groups" { print "Group list =" $2 }
printme && $1=="age"    { print "Age ="        $2 }
' <(printf "%s\n" "${persons[@]}") txt.ini
```

With:

```
$ typeset -p persons
declare -a persons=([0]="person_0" [1]="person_1" [2]="person_2")
```

Both sets of `awk` code generate:

```
person_0
Group list =0,1,2
Age =30

person_1
Group list =0,4
Age =28

person_2
Group list =3,4
Age =30
```

**NOTE:** this could be made more dynamic (`public` and/or `private`? different fields?) but that'll entail a bit more coding

Comment: How can I collect the data from only one person? Eg. person_0 and not print all.  I mean in the top of the code I have a variable which choose one person eg. at this time x="person_0" and how can I set group and age variables?